# Union Filtering

Tags: typescript, union

This is most probably a duplicate but I could not find anything that could solve this issue after googling for probably over 30 minutes.

Let's say I have a union type of strings and numbers, is it possible to filter that so that I would end up with a union type that has only strings or only numbers?

Something along the lines of

```ts
type all = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 1 | 2 | 3

type numbers = Filter<all, 'number'> // 1 | 2 | 3

type strings = Filter<all, 'string'> // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

or

```ts
type all = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 1 | 2 | 3

type numbers = Filter<all, value => value is number> // 1 | 2 | 3

type strings = Filter<all, value => value is string> // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Comment: `type numbers = all & number;`  Remember that types are sets.

Comment: You can also use `Extract<All, number>` (the convention is UpperCamelCase for custom types, even unions of primitives).  Maybe @MattTimmermans should write up an answer (unless someone has a good duplicate candidate)?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I did not use it earlier because I had thought that Extract<..., a | b | c> would only return those exact values (so in the number example, Extract<'a' | 1, number> would return never and Extract<'a' | number, number> would return number). Thanks for the answer!